Any connection between weak derivatives and total differentialbility?
So if we have $u \in H^s(\mathbb{R}^3)$ with $s \geq 3$, do we also have the known Taylor formula for u if it is strongly differentiable? Meaning:
\begin{equation*}
u(x+p) = u(x) + \nabla u(x) \cdot p + R(p)
\end{equation*}
With $\lim_{p \rightarrow 0^+} \frac{R(p)}{|p|} = 0$
Of course this should be hold only almost everywhere.Or do we need some extra conditions for this to hold.

We have $H^s(\mathbb{R}^3)=W^{s,2}(\mathbb{R}^3)$. However, by Sobolev's inequality we know that for $n<kp$ we have the embedding $$ W^{k,p}(\mathbb{R}^n) \subseteq C^{r,\alpha}(\mathbb{R}^n) $$ with $$r+\alpha = k-\frac{n}{p}.  $$ For you $k=s\geq 3, p=2$ and $n=3$. Thus, $n=3<3\cdot 2 \leq nk$ and $$ r+\alpha = k -\frac{n}{p} = s-\frac{3}{2}\geq \frac{3}{2}. $$ In particular, this means that $u$ has a representative which is $C^1$ with Hölder continuous derivative (thus, Taylor still works).

We have $H^s(\mathbb{R}^3)=W^{s,2}(\mathbb{R}^3)$. However, by Sobolev's inequality we know that for $n<kp$ we have the embedding $$ W^{k,p}(\mathbb{R}^n) \subseteq C^{r,\alpha}(\mathbb{R}^n) $$ with $$r+\alpha = k-\frac{n}{p}.  $$ For you $k=s\geq 3, p=2$ and $n=3$. Thus, $n=3<3\cdot 2 \leq nk$ and $$ r+\alpha = k -\frac{n}{p} = s-\frac{3}{2}\geq \frac{3}{2}. $$ In particular, this means that $u$ has a representative which is $C^1$ with Hölder continuous derivative (thus, Taylor still works). This does in fact tell you that you could get away with $s>\frac{5}{2}$.

If $s$ is an integer, then the answer is yes. The result is Theorem 6.5 in Evans-Gariepy. I do not know the answer for non-integer $s$.
